# Debezium MySQL Connector - Primary Server Configuration for binlog_row_image setting

Tags: mysql, debezium, mysqlbinlog, binlog

We have a primary MySQL server and a secondary/replica server. Debezium connector is configured to read from the replica server.

Per the [Debezium documentation](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/mysql.html#enable-mysql-binlog), we configured the below settings on the **replica server only**. Also did a replica server restart.

```
binlog_format     = ROW
binlog_row_image  = FULL
```

On the primary server the binlog_row_image is set to MINIMAL.

While this configuration worked fine for the initial-snapshot data, further updates to data in the primary server caused the Debezium to throw the below error:

```
ava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected value for JDBC type 12 and column coupon_code VARCHAR(45) CHARSET latin1 NOT NULL: class=class java.time.LocalDateTime
```

The error went away after the binlog_row_image was set to FULL on the primary server also.

**Question:**
Aren't the binlogs independent on the primary and replica servers? If so, what is the need for us to set the binlog_row_image = FULL on the primary as well?

Note: our intention is to avoid making this above setting on primary due to the concerns of increase in storage and possible impact on server performance.

**UPDATE**

Below is the output of the SHOW CREATE TABLE statement on both primary and replica. The results were IDENTICAL.

```
CREATE TABLE `admin_user` (
   `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'User ID',
   `firstname` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'User First Name',
   `lastname` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'User Last Name',
   `email` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'User Email',
   `username` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'User Login',
   `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'User Password',
   `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'User Created Time',
   `modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'User Modified Time',
   `is_active` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 'User Is Active',
   `interface_locale` varchar(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'en_US' COMMENT 'Backend interface locale',
   `lock_expires` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Expiration Lock Dates',
   PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
   UNIQUE KEY `ADMIN_USER_USERNAME` (`username`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=337 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Admin User Table'
```

Also, note that these are Azure Managed Mysql instances.

Comment: Show us  `SHOW CREATE TABLE` on both the Primary and the Replica.

Comment: @RickJames thanks. I have added the results of SHOW CREATE TABLE in the question description section itself.